# Free OCR SDK for .net which can extract text,tables with format and images into Office word document

Tags: c#, ocr, image-recognition

I want to have a free OCR SDK which can extract text, tables with data and images from scanned document files (.tiff,.png etc) and store into Office Word document file.

Please help me to short out this issue. I have already done extracting text only from images using MODI but could not get the way using MODI how to extract tables and images and store into Office Word Document file.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure whether opensource SDKs can solve your tasks. Based on what you describe I see that you need a complex ocr application with document logical structure reconstruction functions. If you are planning business software you may look at [ABBYY FineReader Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk/). It has a set of [document analyzing and reconstruction features](http://www.abbyy.com/ocr_sdk_windows/key_features/adrt/), provides api for c# and it’s free to try. It’s not affordable for free-to-use programs, but when it comes to business software – ABBYY OCR technologies can add a serious value to your product, so consider trying it out. I work @ ABBYY and can provide you additional info if necessary.

Best regards, Nikolay.